# How set "Stack creation options" with serverless?

Tags: javascript, node.js, yaml, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

Cloudformation [supports](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-console-add-tags.html) set `Timeout` via "Stack creation options". But where this section in [serverless.yml](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml/)? Any workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [actual code](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/blob/master/lib/plugins/aws/deploy/lib/createStack.js#L28-L50), the TimeoutInMinutes parameter is not part of the parameters passed to the CreateStack API call, so it is not yet supported.
But a [feature request](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/5814) has already been opened for this.

One solution to overcome long deployment operations could be to split the serverless stack into multiple, independent (not nested) stacks using the [serverless-plugin-additional-stacks](https://github.com/nordcloud/serverless-plugin-additional-stacks) plugin.